# Find min date within data to draw svg using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Im using d3.js to visualise some data, and I'm brand new to both Javascript and SVG etc.

I've got the following code which does work

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 140},
    width = pbi.width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = pbi.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);
      
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.1, 0.2);

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var header = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "header");
  // Title
  header.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("y", 15)
      .text("The visual");

pbi.dsv(function(Data) {
var mindate = new Date('01-01-1905');
var maxdate = new Date();
x.domain([mindate, maxdate]).nice(d3.time.month);
y.domain(Data.map(function(d) { return d.milestone; }));

svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

svg.append("g")
.selectAll(".circle")
.data(Data)
.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(new Date(d.date))} )
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d.milestone)+33; })
    .attr("r", 10);
      });
```

What I want to do next is alter the mindate line so it dynamically finds the lowest date in the dataset. As of now, its hardcoded.

Something like  var mindate = new Date(d3.min(d.date)) but that definitely doesn't work

My data is formatted as follows:

```
{reportingyear:'2016', owner:'***', thing:'a-thing', milestone:'start-date', date:'01/12/10'},
{reportingyear:'2017', owner:'***', thing:'a-thing', milestone:'start-date', date:'01/12/10'},
{reportingyear:'2020', owner:'***', thing:'a-thing', milestone:'start-date', date:'01/12/10'}
```

etc. (De-identified for security reasons!)

Any tips to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

---

After applying the help below, I know am running into the following error
[image]

This code is being developed for use in PowerBI in the d3.js plug in, so the data is actually going to be pulled from the data model, the list data is just to replicate the svg in browser to edit.

Comment: `01/12/10` - is that 1st December 2010, or 12th January 2010, or something else ?

Comment: 12th Jan 2010. I'm using d3js plug in for PowerBI and that is the data structure that it pulls in so I was just trying to replicate that for development

Answer (score 1):

First, if you've got data represented as a list of objects with a date field expressed as a string, you should consider converting those strings to Date objects. It's not immediately clear from your example what the date format is but, assuming it's month/day/year, you could perform that task as

```
data = data.map(function (o) {
  o.date = new Date(o.date);
  return o;
})
```

Then, you could compute the min as

```
d3.min(data, o => o.date)
```

Here's complete code:

```js
let data = [
    {
      reportingyear: "2016",
      owner: "***",
      thing: "a-thing",
      milestone: "start-date",
      date: "01/12/10"
    },
    {
      reportingyear: "2017",
      owner: "***",
      thing: "a-thing",
      milestone: "start-date",
      date: "01/12/10"
    },
    {
      reportingyear: "2020",
      owner: "***",
      thing: "a-thing",
      milestone: "start-date",
      date: "01/12/10"
    }
  ].map(function (o) {
    o.date = new Date(o.date);
    return o;
  });
  
 
  let min_date = d3.min(data, o => o.date)
  console.log(min_date)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Mark. However I am running into the following error code
```
Uncaught TypeError: d3.timeParse is not a function
    at resource.html:104:17
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.dsv (resource.html:103:7)
    at resource.html:141:5
```

This code is being developed for use in PowerBI d3.js plug in. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like PowerBI uses version 3 of D3, which is antiquated. D3 is up to version 7 now with a clear road map for version 8. The easiest quick fix for the immediate problem is to use the Date constructor to parse the date and I've edited the answer accordingly. I'm not sure what other problems might arise down the road, though.